# Gem not initializing within my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have come across an issue with my gem, it seems that it is not initializing when starting the rails server, if i run this script in the console i can access the model classes, however when i start the rails server i get 'uninitialized constant errors'

```
require "blogModels/version"

module BlogModels

 Gem.find_files("models/*.rb").each do |f| 
 filename = File.basename(f, '.*')
 class_name_symbol = filename.classify.to_sym
 autoload class_name_symbol, "models/#{filename}"
end

end
```

my gemfile

```
gem 'mygem', :git => "pathtogem"
```

afterwhich i ran bundle

Would there be a reason as to why it is not loading when i am retrieving it from git?

Thanks

Comment: please issue `bundle show mygem`

Comment: /home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-6a0c241198d8

Comment: What files do you have in your gem lib directory?

Comment: well the gem is located here, been trying different things all day so it has quite a few commits :( https://github.com/richlewis14/blogModels

Comment: so the gem is exist, your have to run your app with `bundle exec bin/your_app`, or `bundle exec rails s` if is rails

Comment: well using rails and bundle exec rails s did not work wither

Comment: what does it mean: don't work?

Comment: i get still get the error "Uninitialized constant Portfolio" for example